# How to sum arrays in nested arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sum

I have a nested array

```
array([[1,2,4], [2,5,6]])
```

I want to sum each array in it to get:

```
array([[7], [13]])
```

How to do that? When I do `np.array([[1,2,4], [2,5,6]])` it gives

`array([7, 13])`

Comment: Do you know how to add a dimension to an array?  `np.sum(arr, axis=1)[:,None]`.  The `keep_dims` parameter is handy, but you should also be familiar with this `None` idiom.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sum` over axis 1:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,4], [2,5,6]])
>>> a.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
[[ 7]
 [13]]
```

Or without numpy:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,4], [2,5,6]]
>>> [[sum(l)] for l in a]
[[7], [13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the `array()` function is, but if its just a list,
then this should work:

```py
a=array([[1,2,4], [2,5,6]])
b=[[sum(x)] for x in a] #new list of answers
```